# ¿Cómo hago aparecer mis imágenes progresivamente al hacer sroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un bloque de imágenes en fila que quiero vayan apareciendo progresivamente (en cascada) al hacer scroll sobre esa sección de la página web, pero, funciona, digamos en bloque. Cada imagen tiene la clase `aparece` y quiero hacer un loop con retardo. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

        let scrollUsuario = $(window).scrollTop();

        let profundidad = $('.aparece').offset().top - $(window).innerHeight() * .8;

        if (scrollUsuario > profundidad) {

            $('.aparece').addClass('ver');

    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres, que las imágenes aparezcan de una en una cada x milisegundos?

Comment: Hola, sí, eso es lo que quiero. Creo que habría que hacer un loop y dentro de ese, la función...

Comment: debes agregar un ejemplo minimo de tu codigo, para poder repodrucir tu error o tu codigo y agregar los cambios pertinentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
if (scrollUsuario > profundidad) {
  $('.aparece').each((i,elem) => {
    setTimeout(()=> $(elem).addClass('ver'), i * 100);
  }
}
```

A cada elemento se le añadirá la clase `ver` cada 0.1 segundos

Comment: Gracias Pablo, sí funciona.